# why runtime error happen? After import Mecab

Tags: mecab

what is problem?
I use python3 windows10 environment is Anaconda

```
m=MeCab.Tagger("-Ochasen")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\a.sakata\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MeCab.py", line 253, in __init__
    _MeCab.Tagger_swiginit(self, _MeCab.new_Tagger(*args))
RuntimeError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dicrc` probably doesn't include the `chasen` format. This causes the Mecab C lib to die with an error, which results in the runtime error in Python.

I get the same error, and if I run mecab on the command line I get this output:

```
$ mecab -Ochasen
writer.cpp(63) [!tmp.empty()] unkown format type [chasen]
```

If you *don't* get an error on the command line the cause might be something else.